# On Windows, is mouse responsiveness affected by CPU load or disk I/O?

Tags: windows, mouse

On my Windows machine, I've recently switched over from a wired USB mouse to a wireless RF mouse. The RF mouse uses a USB "dongle" to connect to my computer.

I've started noticing that at times when my computer was "working hard" the wireless mouse became a little less responsive. The cursor on screen would skip a little when moving or delay before movement is shown.

By "working hard" I mean the computer is doing either CPU intensive job or - if my hearing is accurate - intense disk (HDD) I/O operations.

Does it make sense that one of these things (CPU/disk I/O) would have a negative effect on the wireless mouse but not on the wired mouse?

If it does will I experience a similar effect with all wireless mice or might some models and/or transmission technologies be better than others?

Comment: Its affected by both

Comment: @Ramhound Tx but - Always? For all types of mice? Why does this not affect the wired mouse?

Comment: You asked, if high CPU load or high I/O, would cause Windows to delay moving the mouse cursor or not.  *I answered that question.*

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't affect a wired mouse because the mouse is connected to the CPU directly....unlike a wireless mouse since the CPU is busy it would take a while before the USB DONGLE would send the command to the RF mouse itself before the mouse would start responding.....now! that process is being delayed because your central processing unit (C.P.U) is busy

Comment: A wired mouse is not connected directly to the CPU; at the end of the day, both a wired and wireless mouse are Human Interface Devices (HID) under Windows.